# Create columns with map when a function returns a list

Tags: r, purrr

If I had a function that returned a list and I wanted to `map` over inputs to return that as columns in a data.frame what would be the best approach? For example:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

return_list <- function(arg) {
  if (arg == "bar") {
    return(
      list(
        one = "ele1",
        two = "ele2"
      )
    )
  }
}

tibble(foo = "bar") %>%
  mutate(col = map(foo, return_list))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   foo   col             
#>   <chr> <list>          
#> 1 bar   <named list [2]>
```

What I am hoping for is something like this:

```r
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   foo   one   two  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 bar   ele1  ele2
```

`tidyr::unnest` is available but that seems to more useful when you don't control the iteration step.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative for `unnest` is to use `unnest_wider` to create the new columns. But maybe you are still looking for something to do that in the `map` step?

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(foo = "bar") %>%
  mutate(col = map(foo, return_list)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col)

#  foo   one   two  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 bar   ele1  ele2
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Andrew's approach, but you may also be interested in `data.table`, as below:

```
data.table(foo ="bar")[, c("one", "two"):= return_list(foo)][]
```

Output:

```
      foo    one    two
   <char> <char> <char>
1:    bar   ele1   ele2
```